# Thymeleaf: print a Set in the template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    /** The Serial Version UID for Serializable classes. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserRole() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
...
}
```

and want to print all the roles of a User, so I use this code:

```
 <td class="col_name"   th:text="${user.userRoles.role}"></td><!-- ROLES -->
```

but what I see in the browser is literally this:

```
com.tdk.backend.persistence.domain.backend.User.userRoles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to iterate through the set of objects to print the `role` values.  You can use Thymeleaf's `th:each` syntax to do so:

```
<td class="col_name">
    <span th:each="userRole : ${user.userRoles}" th:text="${userRole.role}">[role]</span><!-- format with line breaks as needed -->
</td>
```

You can alternatively look at the `lists` utility and call the `toString()` to output for a quick and dirty way:

```
<td class="col_name">
    <span th:text="${#lists.toString(user.userRole.role)}">[role]</span>
</td>
```

You can optionally remove the `<span>` tags by using `th:remove="tag"`.